# Элемент Login и своя БД

Tags: asp.net, c#, база-данных

Интересует такой вопрос, можно ли заставить элемент логин сверять данные аутентификации с моей БД?
И ещё, элемент `LoginButton` имеет параметр `CommandName="Login"`, а вот где посмотреть содержимое этой команды не нашёл, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на первый вопрос [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms229862.aspx). То есть можно только, если будут созданы необходимые таблицы и хранимые процедуры через средство регистрации Sql Server - aspnet_regsql.exe.

Comment: Создавал я эти таблицы, там слишком большая структура для моего небольшого веб приложения, похоже проще будет самому набросать небольшую форму авторизации.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал простеньким методом:

```
protected void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ParkConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            string sqlQuery = string.Format("SELECT users, passwords FROM Table1 WHERE (users = '{0}') AND (passwords = '{1}')", tb_user.Text, tb_password.Text); 
            SqlCommand cmd_SQL = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlCon);
            cmd_SQL.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdrSQL = cmd_SQL.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdrSQL.Read())
            { FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(tb_user.Text,false); }
            else { LabelERR.Text = "Неверные данные"; }
        }
```

Comment: Нехорошо хранить пароли в БД в чистом виде. Хорошим решением считается хранить хэш пароля.

Comment: у меня и не стояло целью шифровать их. Это тестовое внутренне веб приложение, доступ к которой имеют только сотрудники предприятия.

Answer (score 0):

Если это веб приложение то лучше стоит использовать свой MembershipProvider
[MembershipProvider на GotDotNet](http://www.gotdotnet.ru/blogs/zhidkov/9955/)